# Python splice data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, split

I have my data split but the `daychange = price.split('(', 1)[1].split('%')[0]` is currently displaying +0.84 but I am struggling to find the best way to separate the 0.84 from the + (since it could also be a -).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p='
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find_all('span')[1].text
daychange = price.split('(', 1)[1].split('%')[0]
#plusminus = price.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0].find('+')
print(daychange)
```

I am sure it is something simple. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In Yahoo!Finance you can have a positive variation `+0.0070(+1.20%)`, negative `-0.24(-0.92%)` or no variation `0.00(0.00%)`. To include all three cases you can test for the first character of the string, if different from zero you can use the remaining string (`daychange[1:]`).

```
...
...
daychange = price.split('(', 1)[1].split('%')[0]
print(daychange)

if daychange[0] != "0":
    plusminus = daychange[0]
    abs_daychange = float(daychange[1:])
else:
    plusminus = ""  # no sign
    abs_daychange = float(daychange)

print((plusminus, abs_daychange))
#('-', 0.62)
```